# How can I use a DataTransformer transform with the FosRestBundle view layer

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I've using a `DataTransformer` on my form to `reverseTransform` a decimal value send by the client into a `Money/Money` object.

This works well as expected, however when I return the data to the client using the FosRestBundle view layer, I'm not sure how I can use that transformer to transform it back into a decimal value for the client?

Comment: Are you using doctrine and then storing it as a decimal in the DB?

Comment: Nope, no doctrine, I'm using DynamoDB so have my own way of persisting data. I'm storing the money values as strings i.e. `"50.25"` and using the entity getters and setters to convert it to and from a `Money` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JMSSerializer with FOSRestBundle the serializer usually accesses the values of your object using reflection so the getters aren't touched.

You can however set the access type for the property or all of the properties in the object to the public method (getters/setters) using the `access_type` setting.

For Annotation you would use..

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\AccessType;

class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @AccessType("public_method")
     */
    private $money;

    ....
}
```

For more info see:
  Annotations: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor
  XML: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/xml_reference
  YAML: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference